# ggmagnify doesn't plot when from values are too close axis edges

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, magnify

I'm creating plots using ggplot2 and ggmagnify in R. I have noticed that when I set the ggmagnify 'from' argument too close to the minimum plot axis values, that magnified plot no longer shows up. I'm not sure if the issue is specific to using `scale_x_continuous` / `scale_y_continous` or if it occurs anytime the magnified box gets too close to the plot edges. It does seem to be an issue with both axes. I have also noticed that on my actual plots, the minimum value I can enter before the plot disappears is smaller for plots with smaller axis value ranges (e.g. a plot with an axis from 0 to 20 works with a from value down to 0.05 while a plot with an axis from 0 to 26 only works with a value down to 0.22).

Is this a bug/issue with ggmagnify or am I missing an element in ggplot or ggmagnify that avoids this issue?

R: 4.3.1; ggplot2: 3.4.3; ggmagnify: 0.2.0.9

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmagnify)
library(cowplot)
set.seed(1)
x <- seq(0,10,1)
y <- sample(x,11)
plist <- vector(mode = "list", length = 4)

# Magnified plot shows up with from = c(0.25, 5, 0.25, 5)
plist[[1]] <- ggplot(data=data.frame(x,y)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(x=x,y=y), height = 0) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 10)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 10)) +
  coord_cartesian(clip="off") +
  geom_magnify(from=c(0.25, 5, 0.25, 5),to=c(11, 21, 0.45, 9.5), axes = "xy")

# Magnified plot does not show up with from = c(0.20, 5, 0.20, 5)
plist[[2]] <- ggplot(data=data.frame(x,y)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(x=x,y=y), height = 0) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 10)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 10)) +
  coord_cartesian(clip="off") +
  geom_magnify(from=c(0.20, 5, 0.20, 5),to=c(11, 21, 0.45, 9.5), axes = "xy")

plot_grid(plotlist = plist, align = "hv", byrow = FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to fix your issue would be to set the limits via `coord_cartesian` instead of via the scale. The latter will remove all data points and all "ink" which falls outside of the limits, whereas setting the limits via the coord does not:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmagnify)
#> Warning: package 'ggmagnify' was built under R version 4.3.1
library(cowplot)
set.seed(1)
x <- seq(0, 10, 1)
y <- sample(x, 11)
plist <- vector(mode = "list", length = 4)

# Magnified plot shows up with from = c(0.25, 5, 0.25, 5)
plist[[1]] <- ggplot(data = data.frame(x, y)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(x = x, y = y), height = 0) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 10), ylim = c(0, 10), clip = "off") +
  geom_magnify(from = c(0.25, 5, 0.25, 5), to = c(11, 21, 0.45, 9.5), axes = "xy")

# Magnified plot does not show up with from = c(0.20, 5, 0.20, 5)
plist[[2]] <- ggplot(data = data.frame(x, y)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(x = x, y = y), height = 0) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 10), ylim = c(0, 10), clip = "off") +
  geom_magnify(from = c(0.20, 5, 0.20, 5), to = c(11, 21, 0.45, 9.5), axes = "xy")

plot_grid(plotlist = plist, align = "hv", byrow = FALSE)
```

[image]